# Zero-Multiplicity Property related to Gelfand Pairs and Spherical Representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, branching-rules

Say I have a Lie group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H$. Consider representations over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

We say that $(G,H)$ is a Gelfand pair if *for any irrep* $\rho$ of $G$, we have $\mathrm{dim} \mathrm{Hom}_H(\rho,\mathbb{C}) \leq 1$ (meaning that the restricted representation $\rho|_H$ decomposes into at most one copy of the trivial irrep).

However, suppose $(G,H)$ has this "Gelfand property" only *for some* irreps of $\rho$ of $G$ (but not for all of them). Has this been studied in the literature before?

I know that if you study this for irreps $\rho$ such that $\mathrm{dim} \mathrm{Hom}_H(\rho,\mathbb{C}) = 1$ then $\rho$ is called a spherical representation. However, I am actually more interested in those $\rho$ such that $\mathrm{dim} \mathrm{Hom}_H(\rho,\mathbb{C}) = 0$ (in other words, I am interested in those irreps $\rho$ such that the restricted representation $\rho|_H$ decomposes into zero copies of the trivial irrep, i.e., the trivial irrep has zero multiplicity).

Comment: Note that if $G$ and $H$ are semisimple (which I assume they likely are since you talk about the reps decomposing) this can be quantified as those reps whose highest weight restricts to a weight for $H$ that is not in its root lattice.

Comment: By "these" I mean the reps with no trivial subrep. Realised I didn't make that clear.